# Can I ask a question for clarification of an answer?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Suppose that I received a somehow terse answer or an answer which is a little bit beyond my level, and that I would like to understand the answer in some more detail. Is it appropriate to ask a question in which I expect to receive an answer explaining and elaborating on that answer?

Comment: As a first step you could ask for clarification via a comment on the answer.

Comment: @quid I would feel embarrassed if I do that because I already asked for many things and the user edited their answer several times.

Comment: You could also place a bounty on the question, giving as reason that you seek a more detailed answer.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4108),

Comment: But, please, don't just write, "can you clarify that?" That gives the answerer nothing to go on, no idea of what part of her two-page answer you're having trouble with. If you ask for clarification, be as specific as you can possibly be as to where exactly the difficulty is.